# Open webpage and parse it using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, html

I know JavaScript can open a link in a new window but is it possible to open a webpage without opening it in a window or displaying it to the user? What I want to do is parse that webpage for some text and use it as variables.

Is this possible **without** any help from server side languages? If so, please send me in a direction I can achieve this.

Thanks all

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use an [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) object to do this. Here's a simple example

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();  
req.open('GET', 'http://www.mydomain.com/', false);   
req.send(null);  
if(req.status == 200)  
   dump(req.responseText);
```

Once loaded, you can perform your parsing/scraping by using [javascript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) on the req.responseText member.

### More detail...

In practice you need to do a little more to get the XMLHttpRequest object in a cross platform manner, e.g.:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if (!window.ActiveXObject)
  req = new XMLHttpRequest();
else if (ua.indexOf('msie 5') == -1)
  req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
else
  req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

### Or use a library...

Alternatively, you can save yourself all the bother and just use a library like [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) or [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax) to take care of this for you.

### Same-origin policy may bite you though...

Note that due to the [same-origin policy](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#same-origin), the page you request must be from the same domain as the page making the request. If you want to request a remote page, you will have to proxy that via a server side script.

Another possible workaround is to use Flash to make the request, which does allow cross-domain requests if the target site grants permission with a suitably configured crossdomain.xml file.

Here's a nice article on the subject of the same-origin policy:

- [Same-Origin Policy Part 1: Why we’re stuck with things like XSS and XSRF/CSRF](http://taossa.com/index.php/2007/02/08/same-origin-policy/)

Comment: Damn! I wwas hoping for an external page, so because of CSC JavaScript is not allowed to parse text from an external web page?

Comment: Not so much parsing but the XMLHttpRequest is forbidden from fetching from another domain. The workaround is to request via your own server-side script, or you could try using a small iframe.

Comment: I understand now. It will have to be a server side implementation then.

Comment: Having said that, I know Flash can let you do cross domain requests as long as the target site is configured to allow them. Will add to answer

Answer (score 8):

Whatever Origin is an open source library that allows you to use purely Javascript to do scraping. It also solves the "same-domain-origin" problem.
http://www.whateverorigin.org/

```
$.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://google.com') + '&callback=?', function(data){
    alert(data.contents);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try using fetch and it's callback

```
fetch('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=google.com').then((response) => response.text()).then((text) => console.log(text));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could open the new window in an iframe:

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp

Although note that Javascript access is limited if the site you open is from a different URL. This is to prevent cross-site scripting attacks:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: +1 this is what I'd do if the site isn't mine and doesn't support pjson callbacks

Answer (score 3):

You would use AJAX.  This would make a Get request to the URL in question and return the response HTML.  Jquery makes this very easy e.g.

```
$.get("test.php");
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax

Andrew