# I want to extract and parse text and files from a site, translate the extracted text and then post it to another website

Tags: php, parsing

I want to extract text and files from a dll-files.com.
The text will be the name and description. The files will be of .dll format.

I want to translate the text and description into Swedish and then post the text and dll files onto a phpBB forum.
Please suggest any solution to this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is five topics in one, and you're not really asking a question. It would be better if you'd split them up. And please clarify the first step. Where are you fetching the contents from - a web site? What does the DLL format have to do with that?

Comment: I want to extract stuff from dll-files.com

Comment: as said, you're asking five (or more) questions in one, and extracting data from a DLL file is near impossible in PHP anyway. ALso, I very much doubt what you are planning to do is legal.

Comment: I want to extract dll files from dll-files.com . I dont want to extract data from dll files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check google's translate API, they usually do a decent job.
As for getting the data from dll-files.com, you could ask them for an API of some sorts, or attempt to scrape it.

There are several HTML-parsing libraries out there, all you have to do is get the content of the right element. However, make sure you dont violate http://dll-files.com's terms.

http://code.google.com/apis/language/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to parse the HTML contents of relevant pages on dll-files.com, so that the description of the DLL is available in Swedish, and so that you can provide a direct link, rather than redirecting to an English page. Is that what you meant?

If so, the solution you are looking for may have already been answered on this site, at the following link:

[Open webpage and parse it using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597907/open-webpage-and-parse-it-using-javascript)

Comment: There is actually no need to translate the page into Swedish. Any swede interested in installing DLL-files will know enough English to work from the current page.