# How can I get text from any specified webpage in to a variable?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the text from the page https://domains.google.com/checkip
 into a variable using only javascript. Is this possible?

Comment: here is a related question that should do what you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open webpage and parse it using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597907/open-webpage-and-parse-it-using-javascript)

Comment: In general this is not possible because of [Same-Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). However, *if and only if* the foreign site participates in [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (for the requested resource) then it's possible to use a cross-domain AJAX request.

Comment: @user2864740 it does not participate in CORS, by design, as stated in my answer.

Comment: Why make things more complicated? This is a very general task in web-development and usually gets done via AJAX request to some internal  server-side script that grabs the data from remote hosts.

Answer (score 4):

No it's not possible because that page (https://domains.google.com/checkip) prevents cross-domain requests by *not* placing an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the HTTP response.

You can't even put the page in an `iframe` because the header `x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN` prevents it from being embedded by compliant browsers as well.